# How should Scala default arguments to refer to a previous positional argument?

Tags: scala, constructor, operator-precedence, default-parameters, default-arguments

Scala-lang reference 5.5.1 and 6.6.1 gave me the impression that a default parameter would be able to refer to a previously evaluated one:

```
class Test(val first: String, val second: String = first)
```

but from experimenting it seems the only way to do this is to use the form:

```
class Test(val first: String)(val second: String = first)
```

and then define an auxiliary constructor or a creational companion class to avoid specifying the second set of brackets when creating. I don't really understand how this second constructor works, it looks like a curried function so I might guess that it is necessary to evaluate `first` independently of `second`, is this correct? Is this form necessary or is there some syntatic sugar I can use to tweak the first constructor into doing what I want?

Comment: There is no (sub)section 5.5.1 in the [current Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/linuxsoft_archives/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf). Did you mean 5.1.1 ("Constructor Invocations")?

Comment: Yes should have been 5.1.1. As @Travis Brown pointed out section 5.3 defining the scoping of the parameters as they are being evaluated would explain the compilation error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [Travis Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334519/travis-brown) points out, you can indeed only refer to a previous argument in a default expression when it is from a previous argument list (so you do need to currify).

Now, regarding your particular use case, default arguments and method overloading are sometimes two ways of achieving the same thing.

I think the simplest solution to your scenario is simply to define `Test` as follows:

```
class Test(val first : String, val second : String) {
  def this(f : String) = this(f, f)
}
```

If you want to make it more complicated, an alternative way, using a companion object:

```
class Test(val first : String)(val second : String = first)
object Test {
  def apply(f : String) = new Test(f)
  def apply(f : String, s : String) = new Test(f)(s)
}
```

(A small difference is that now you create objects without `new`.)

What you **cannot** do, is define it as:

```
class Test(val first : String)(val second : String = first) {
  def this(f : String, s : String) = this(f)(s)
}
```

...because the curried version gets translated into (among other things) a method with the same signature as the overloaded contructor.

Answer (score 7):

From 5.3 of [the spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf):

> The scope of a formal value parameter includes all subsequent
>   parameter sections and the template *t*.

Regular methods are the same, by the way (from 4.6):

> The scope of a formal value parameter name *x* comprises all
>   subsequent parameter clauses, as well as the method return type and
>   the function body, if they are given.

I.e., whether you've got a constructor or an ordinary method, a value parameter name isn't in scope in its own parameter clause. In your second version the constructor has two parameter clauses, and `first` is only in scope in the second. See 5.3 for more detail about multiple parameter clauses.